# how to set tooltip using javascript in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, tooltip

I have a text box in my aspx page. I need show its tooltip when and only when the text box is disabled/greyed out. How do I achieve this using JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call this function where you enable/disable the textbox

```
function setToolTip()
{
    if(document.getElementById("myTextBox").disabled == true)
    {
        document.getElementById("myTextBox").title="ToolTip";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("myTextBox").title="";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
document.getElementById("<%=TextBox.ClientID%>").setAttribute('title','New Tooltip');
```

2nd way:

```
function DisplayToolTip()
        {
            document.getElementById('divToolTip').style.left = window.event.x;
            document.getElementById('divToolTip').style.top = window.event.y;

            document.getElementById('divToolTip').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }

        function HideToolTip()
        {
            document.getElementById('divToolTip').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
```

Now add the below HTML markup code:

```
    <span id="spanName" style="font-weight: bold;border: solid 2px red;" 
onmouseover="javascript:DisplayToolTip();"
        onmouseout="javascript:HideToolTip();">THIS IS THE SPAN
    </span>


   <div id="divToolTip" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;
   z-index: 20; background-color: white; border: solid 1px Blue;">
   This is ToolTip Text
   </div>
```